# Calling session_write_close() before Zend_Session::start() in the bootstrap causes an error

Tags: php, zend-framework, session

So I need access to an existing Session from Zend.  Don't ask why, I don't like to talk about it.  Anyway, I've gotten as far as discovering that I can access it from the bootstrap before I initialize my session.  I have the following code in place to attempt to pull it out and transfer it over:

```
 protected function _initSession() {
        session_start();
        $values = $_SESSION;
        session_write_close();

        $db = Zend_Db::factory('Pdo_Mysql', array(
            'host'        =>'localhost',
            'username'    => 'uname',
            'password'    => '******',
            'dbname'    => 'dbname'
        ));
        Zend_Db_Table_Abstract::setDefaultAdapter($db);


        $sessionConfig = array( 
            'name'           => 'Sessions',      
            'primary'        => 'sessionID',   
            'modifiedColumn' => 'lastModifiedTime',     
            'dataColumn'     => 'data',
            'lifetimeColumn' => 'lifetime'
        ); 
        $saveHandler = new Zend_Session_SaveHandler_DbTable($sessionConfig); 
        Zend_Session::setSaveHandler($saveHandler); 
        Zend_Session::start();

        $old = new Zend_Session_Namespace('OLD');
        $old->values = $values;
}
```

It's choking when it hits `Zend_Session::start()`, claiming that a session has already been started.  But I've called `session_write_close()` to close the session and as far as I can tell from my google-fu there's nothing wrong with restarting a previously cosed session.  So why is it choking?  Is it something specific to ZF?  Is there something more I need to do to close the session?  What gives?

Comment: While I don't think anything stops you from closing and reopening a session, I've never seen anyone actually switch session storage methods in the process.  Speaking of storage methods, how is this question significantly different from [the last question you asked about ZF's session handling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5411288/how-can-i-keep-zend-framework-from-wiping-out-an-existing-session)?  Really, the same solution still applies: stop storing the session in the database (thus installing the session handler).

Comment: @Charles That solution isn't available to me.  Sorry, not my call.  I need a solution that allows me to use the database saving.

Comment: @Charles And I suppose it's still the same issue, just been working on it so long and tried so many different things that it felt like a whole new question!

Comment: @Daniel, my condolences on the out-of-your-hands aspect of the difficulties.  I don't think this is solveable as-is.  Can you tell us more about what the session data is in the legacy app?  There might be sane ways to get to that data without trying to make PHP bend over backwards.

Comment: I think you have to handle this with 2 Requests you cant close/open an session in the same http request.

Comment: If all you need is migrate legacy app to a new session storage, maybe take a look how the SaveHandler_DbTable works and write a simple cli scripts as a migration tools.

Comment: register_shutdown_function(array('Zend_Session', 'writeClose'), true); try adding to bootstrap file at bottom

Answer (score 0):

You just can't.

Foremost, as described in the [ZF documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.session.advanced_usage.html#zend.session.advanced_usage.starting_a_session) :

> Do not use PHP's » session_start() function directly. If you use session_start() directly, and then start using Zend_Session_Namespace, an exception will be thrown by Zend_Session::start() ("session has already been started").

So your code must looks like that :

```
    Zend_Session::start();
    $values = $_SESSION;
    Zend_Session::writeClose();
```

But in Zend/Session.php:418, we have :

```
    if (self::$_sessionStarted && self::$_destroyed) {
        require_once 'Zend/Session/Exception.php';
        throw new Zend_Session_Exception('The session was explicitly destroyed during this request, attempting to re-start is not allowed.');
    }
```

So, the way you do the things is unsupported by ZF (like suggested : either with two different requests or with a batch script).

Answer (score 0):

I face same issue today, so I read your blog but still did research , so I find a way which I am sharing with you.

Just use php "session_start()" rather then "Zend_Session::start();"

"Zend_Session::start();" doesn't work after session close so you can go with php session_start();

If you find any good solution please update me :)